# Computed Column Date Leap Year issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns, leap-year

I have a table of names and associated birthdates. I can retrieve the names of everyone whose birthday is today by matching the MONTH and DAY dateparts between the birthdate in the database and the current date. However, I need to pull "looking forward" lists of, say, all birthdays in the next two weeks.

The obvious solution would be a computed column for each person, showing his/her "birthday this year". It's easy to pull the month and day from the birthday, add the current year, and cast the whole string as a date. That way I could just retrieve those whose "birthday this year" is within X days of the current date. However, I have one person with a birthday on February 29, and there isn't a Feb. 29 every year, so the calculated column "chokes" when I query or open the table with the following error:

> The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Suggestions on a way to either make a computed column work properly in this situation, or an alternative way to query using the date of birth in the table?

Comment: 1) Show us your current computed column. 2) Why would you convert it to a string? Date operations should always be kept as dates, which will solve you issue.

Comment: What you store in DB ? How you convert currently ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your query from using `convert` to using `try_convert` which will not error on nonexistent date but will instead return NULL. This will exclude your Feb 29 birthday client if running year is not leap.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work for the end of December, because the year changes.  Here is a different approach:

1. Add the number of years to the date *and let the database handle leap years*.
2. Then do the comparison.

So, the logic for the first is:

```
select dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob)
```

Then to get dates of birth in the next two weeks:

```
where dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) >= convert(date, getdate()) and
      dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) < dateadd(14, day, convert(date, getdate())
```

However, this still doesn't handle dates of birth that could be *next* year.  So, to handle the end of year, consider that as well:

```
where (dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) >= convert(date, getdate()) and
       dateadd(year, year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) < dateadd(14, day, convert(date, getdate())
      ) or
      (dateadd(year, 1 + year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) >= convert(date, getdate()) and
       dateadd(year, 1 + year(getdate()) - year(dob), dob) < dateadd(14, day, convert(date, getdate())
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this - you need to calculate the current year's DOB and the persons next date of birth.  To calculate the current year date of birth we can use a simple calculation:

```
dateadd(year, datediff(year, DateOfBirth, CurrentDate), DateOfBirth)
```

Then - we need to calculate the next date of birth, which is simply adding a year if the current year DOB is less than CurrentDate:

```
dateadd(year, iif(CurrentDOB < CurrentDate, 1, 0), CurrentDOB)
```

Now - it is just a matter of checking if the next DOB is in the range.  Here is some sample data to show how to put this together.

```
 --==== Some sample dates of birth - including leap year DOB's
Declare @testData Table (DateOfBirth date);
 Insert Into @testData (DateOfBirth)
 Values ('1992-01-09'), ('2020-02-29'), ('1965-09-30'), ('1984-02-29');

 --==== Test using different dates
Declare @current_date date = '2021-02-28';

 --==== Use CROSS APPLY to calculate current year DOB and Next DOB
 Select *
   From @testData                                                                                       As td
  Cross Apply (Values (dateadd(year, datediff(year, td.DateOfBirth, @current_date), td.DateOfBirth)))   As y(CurrentDOB)
  Cross Apply (Values (dateadd(year, iif(y.CurrentDOB < @current_date, 1, 0), y.CurrentDOB)))           As n(NextDOB)
  Where n.NextDOB <= dateadd(day, 14, @current_date);
```

If today is 2021-02-28 then the birthdays that fall on the 29th will be included.  If today is 2021-03-01 then those will not be included because they would be calculated as 2022-02-28 which is not within 14 days.